# Dropdown menu not showing when mapping through array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I admit the title is a bit ambiguous, but here is my issue.

I am working on a Laravel project that implements ReactJS on the front end and I'm trying to create a drop down menu that allows users to choose the status of a project. I'm referencing a constants file to get the statuses and their ids, and then mapping through the array to render each item. However, doing it this way means the menu never shows - BUT...if I wrap the whole shebang in a div it does.

Here's the code for how I want the items to be rendered:

```
const StatusItems = () => {

    const statusArray = [
        constant.STATUS_PENDING_ID = constant.STATUS_PENDING,
        constant.STATUS_PROGRESS_ID = constant.STATUS_PROGRESS,
        constant.STATUS_REVIEW_ID = constant.STATUS_REVIEW,
        constant.STATUS_CLOSED_ID = constant.STATUS_CLOSED
    ];

    return (
        statusArray.map(function (status, index) {
            return (
                <DropdownButtonItem>
                    {status}
                </DropdownButtonItem>
            );
        })
    )
};
```

And then the the menu is rendered like so:

```
return (

    <div id="case-status-button" className={ styles['case__status-button'] }>

        <DropdownButton
            isMenuOpen={ props.isStatusMenuOpen }
            onMenuClose={ props.onStatusMenuClose }
            icon="speaker_notes">

            <StatusItems/>

        </DropdownButton>

    </div>
)
```

For some reason, nothing appears when I click the icon for the menu (there is no error or warning either just nothing) - but wrapping the statuses in a div, it works:

```
const StatusItems = () => {

    const statusArray = [
        constant.STATUS_PENDING_ID = constant.STATUS_PENDING,
        constant.STATUS_PROGRESS_ID = constant.STATUS_PROGRESS,
        constant.STATUS_REVIEW_ID = constant.STATUS_REVIEW,
        constant.STATUS_CLOSED_ID = constant.STATUS_CLOSED
    ];

    return (
        <div>
        {statusArray.map(function (status, index) {
            return (
                <DropdownButtonItem>
                    {status}
                </DropdownButtonItem>
            );
        })}
        </div>
    )
};
```

The problem with this is, it disrupts the styling and symantics since I'm inserting a `<div>` into a `<ul>` above the `<li>` elements.

```
<ul>
    <div>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Like that.

Can anyone shed any light on the reason why it only works when I wrap a div around the map?

**Edit**

The `<DropdownButton>` component renders this:

```
return (
    <ul id="dropdown-list" className={ style['dropdown-menu'] }>
        { props.items }
    </ul>
)
```

and the `<DropdownButtonItem>` renders this:

```
return (
    <li styleName="item" onClick={ this.props.onClick }>
        { this.props.children }
    </li>
)
```

Comment: try wrapping it with `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't do the trick either

Comment: btw, i don't see any `li`'s or `ul`'s in your code..

Comment: The component `<DropdownButton>` is the `<ul>` and `<DropdownButtonItem>` is the `<li>`

Comment: I've added the component code in there now

Comment: shouldn't `DropdownButton` render `children` as well?  you're not passing any `items` prop but you do pass `children`

Comment: and why kind of syntax is `statusArray`? doesn't seem valid javascript

Comment: Yes it does - actually `DropdownButton` is two levels deep. Just to clarify, all the other parts of the site using this component work fine, but I'm not mapping through anything in those, just hard coding each `DropdownButtonItem`

Comment: statusArray is just an array.

Comment: this is not a valid member of an array -> `constant.STATUS_PENDING_ID = constant.STATUS_PENDING,`

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted in this question can't and shouldn't work as is, for reasons i stated above. i believe if you provide [mcve] it would help

Comment: Have posted an answer to my question

Comment: `<React.Fragment>` should have worked, what version of React are you using ?

Comment: I'm using React version 15.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the mapping directly inside the main render.

```
<DropdownButton
    isMenuOpen={ props.isStatusMenuOpen }
    onMenuClose={ props.onStatusMenuClose }
    closeOnOutsideClick={ !props.isTourInProgress }
    icon="speaker_notes">

    {
        statusArray.map(function (status, index) {
            return (
                <DropdownButtonItem>
                    {status.label}
                </DropdownButtonItem>
            );
        })
    }

</DropdownButton>
```

And I also changed the structure of the status list so it was an array of objects:

```
const statusArray = [
    {
        label : constant.STATUS_PENDING,
        value : constant.STATUS_PENDING_ID
    },
    {
        label : constant.STATUS_PROGRESS,
        value : constant.STATUS_PROGRESS_ID
    },
    {
        label : constant.STATUS_REVIEW,
        value : constant.STATUS_REVIEW_ID
    },
    {
        label : constant.STATUS_CLOSED,
        value : constant.STATUS_CLOSED_ID
    }
];
```